# Validation with Sequelize IsIn is not allowing only values in Array

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

I have a ReactJS Frontend that takes the value of a `select` and sends it to the backend to be saved to the database. But I want only allowed options to be saved. I am using ORM Sequelize.

***Note:*** Data is arriving correctly in the backend, but even disallowed values are being saved to the database.

Node version: v10.16.2
Sequelize version: 5.19.0

```js
purchase_unit: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
  validade: {
    notNull: {
      msg: 'The field "purchase unit" must be entered'
    },
    notEmpty: {
      msg: 'The field "purchase unit" cannot be empty'
    },
    isIn: {
      args: [["Und", "Pct"]],
      msg: 'Entry not allowed for field "purchase unit"'
    }
  }
}
```

---

```js
<select
    value={productPurchaseUnit}
    onChange={e => setProductPurchaseUnit(e.target.value)}
>
    <option value="Und">Und</option>
    <option value="Pct">Pct</option>
    <option value="m2">m²</option>
    <option value="g">g</option>
    <option value="Kg">Kg</option>
    <option value="Cm">Cm</option>
    <option value="Mt">Mt</option>
</select>
```

According to [official documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html) The *isIn* option should be used as follows:

```js
isIn: {
  args: [['en', 'zh']],
  msg: "Must be English or Chinese"
}
```

Comment: You have validate spelled wrong! :)

Comment: I can’t believe it. thanks @MikeFeltman

Comment: I know your question is already resolved. You can also have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi joi package which provides a much better way for validations. I hope it helps.